# Offsetting Overlapping Symbols in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, symbology, overlapping-features

I am working on a recreational atlas in ArcMap 10.5 that highlights points along the coast including marinas, mooring spots, kayaking and diving points etc. The problem I am facing is that I have so many points that it is just way to crowded with the labels and symbols and the points overlap and it is hard to see what is actually in that spot. I have an example here.

[image]

I was wondering if there was any tool or option to offset the symbols like in labeling or if I will have to offset the layers symbols individually.

Comment: The extra cost Cartography Toolbox is your best bet (other than manually resizing and moving) the other unfortunate is this requires the advance license level for arcgis desktop https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/cartography-toolbox-license.htm

Comment: Maybe you could consider thinning out your data by only mapping the significant point of interest? Do you really need two kayak symbols for one bay? You seem to have a stack of points in some places, maybe just one will suffice? Mapping is often compromise and generalisation.